# How i can access Virtual Directory in ASP.NET MVC 3 Models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In Controller it's easy to access the virtual path you need to access like:

```
Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\blah\blah")
```

This give you access to AppData folder, but if I want to access them in Models, how can I acccess the virtual path in MVC 3?

How can I access my app_data folder in Models of my application ?

Comment: Gupta Why do you need to do this? There shouldn't be a reason to do this, as it violates the separation of concerns. Can you let us know why so we can help you?

Comment: @ i thing that i broke the rule. i need to pass it if i want to use them in Models. Thanks all for support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i were you, rather than figuring out how to access the current execution path, I wouldn't break my App layers and pass it as an argument to my model

Answer (score 3):

Your model should not access it - get the controller to provide the data needed.

Answer (score 0):

As Aliostad said, you should have the Controller access it, the model should only hold model data. So here are 2 ways to use the controller to access it.

If virtual folder is in the root of the web application. (If you have to drill down further, just add more parameters to the path combine until you get to your folders location.)

```
string folderPath = Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(Request.ApplicationPath, "VirtualFolderName"));
```

For a more re-usable solution i created a Extension for the Controller class:

```
using System.IO;   
using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Extensions {
        public static class ControllerExtensions {
            public static string ResolveVirtualFolderPath(this Controller controller, string folder_name) => controller?.HttpContext?.Server?.MapPath(Path.Combine(controller?.HttpContext?.Request?.ApplicationPath, folder_name));                
    }
}
```

Then in the Controller put the using statement so you can access the extension

```
using static Extensions.ControllerExtensions;
```

then you can do this in the controller:

```
string folderPath = this.ResolveVirtualFolderPath("VirtualFolderNameHere");
```

You could break the extension down to not use the null check operator "?" and do if null and then handle each situation like the folder does not exist, or maybe access to location is not allowed or whatever else your needs may be.